# Using jooq-sbt-plugin with ojdbc

Tags: scala, sbt, jooq, ojdbc, jooq-sbt-plugin

I'm using [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org). Solving an issue with `jooq-sbt-plugin` config ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329458/how-to-configure-jooq-sbt-plugin)) resulted in a classpath issue which I think is separate from the original one. I managed to get the configuration to work but trying to get it play with Oracle drivers seems impossible.

The issue here is that the plugin seems run its own `java` process and hence the required classpath (with `odbc14.jar` in it) is never passed on. Is there any way to get the plugin work? I couldn't figure out how to inject to the plugin's classpath.

The only workaround I can come up with is by defining a task instead (described here: https://gist.github.com/chris-martin/5140754).

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**2013-09-10 Update**

Here's the config:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import JOOQPlugin._

object SampleBuild extends Build {

    lazy val all = Project(id = "all", base = file("."), settings = defaultSettings) aggregate(
      one, two
    )

    lazy val one = Project(
        id = "one",
        base = file("one"),
        settings = defaultSettings ++ Seq(
            libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.one
        )
    )

    lazy val two = Project(
        id = "two",
        base = file("two"),
        settings = defaultSettings ++ jooqSettings ++ customJooqSettings ++  Seq(
            libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.two
        )
    ) dependsOn (one)

    override lazy val settings = super.settings ++ buildSettings

    lazy val buildSettings = Seq(
        organization := "org.sample",
        version      := "0.1-SNAPSHOT",
        scalaVersion := "2.10.2"
    )

    lazy val defaultSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
        scalacOptions in Compile ++= scalacParams,
        externalResolvers in Compile := Resolvers.commonResolvers,
        shellPrompt  := ShellPrompt.buildShellPrompt,
        resolvers ++= Resolvers.commonResolvers
    )

    lazy val customJooqSettings = Seq(
        jooqOptions := jooqBvpOptions,
        jooqOutputDirectory := new java.io.File("../src/appdb/src/main/java")
        )

    lazy val jooqBvpOptions = Seq(
        "jdbc.driver"                    -> "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
        "jdbc.url"                       -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<some server>",
        "jdbc.user"                      -> "<some user>",
        "jdbc.password"                  -> "<some pwd>",
        "generator.database.name"        -> "org.jooq.util.oracle.OracleDatabase",
        "generator.database.inputSchema" -> "<some schema>",
        "generator.database.includes"    -> "table1|table2|table3",
        "generator.target.packageName"   -> "org.example.generated")
}

object Resolvers { /* ... */ }

object Dependencies { /* ... */ }

object ShellPrompt { /* ... */ }
```

And here's the error:

```
[info] Initialising properties  : /jooq-config2705409947508036761.xml
[error] Cannot read /jooq-config2705409947508036761.xml. Error : oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
[error]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
[error]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
[error]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
[error]     at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:269)
[error]     at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:123)
[error] Usage : GenerationTool <configuration-file>
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last appdb-tool/jooq:codegen for the full output.
[error] (appdb-tool/jooq:codegen) Failed with return code: 255
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Sep 10, 2013 1:45:24 PM
```

Comment: Could you post your Build.scala, and the exact error you are getting?

Comment: I'll try to clean up our config first thing in the morning. It's nearly 300 lines and contains some customer specific information. Basically the config is the one mentioned with the answer applied to it. The error was ClassNotFoundException for OracleDriver if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[jooq-sbt-plugin](https://github.com/sean8223/jooq-sbt-plugin)'s readme says:

> - Add your database driver to your list of `libraryDependencies` with "jooq" scope:
>
>   ```
>   libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.22" % "jooq"
>   ```

You left out `Dependencies.two` in the above excerpt, but maybe you're missing that.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's possible with Oracle drivers. They're not available in the Maven repository and need to be provided as unmanaged dependencies. I didn't mention this as I thought it was commonly known that Oracle drivers cannot be used in `libraryDependencies`.

Comment: You still have to add them into the classpath of "jooq" configuration whether you use managed dependencies or not.

Comment: Okay, but I really don't get how to do it with unmanaged dependencies. To my understanding, it's not possible.